# Highmaps(HighCharts) loads same map when drilling down

Tags: vue.js, highcharts

I'm faced with a problem while implementing Highmaps.

In my vue project with Webpack, I followed each step explained https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-vue to use Highmaps.

Here's my main.js file

```
//highchart 
import HighchartsVue from 'highcharts-vue'
import Highcharts from 'highcharts'
import WorldMap from '@highcharts/map-collection/custom/world.geo.json'

import USMap from '@highcharts/map-collection/countries/us/us-all.geo.json'
import mapInit from 'highcharts/modules/map.js'
import DrillDown from 'highcharts/modules/drilldown.js'

mapInit(Highcharts);
DrillDown(Highcharts);

Highcharts.maps['world'] = WorldMap;
Highcharts.maps['us'] = USMap;
```

And, here's my vue file

```
<template>

    <div>

        <mymap :mapOptions="mapOptions.options"></mymap>
    </div>
</template>
<script>

export default{

    data(){
        return {
            mapOptions: {
                options: {
                    chart: {
                        map: 'us',
                        events: {
                            drilldown: function(e){
                                var chart = this;



                                 this.addSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, {

                                     data: 'world',
                                     dataLabels: {
                                         enabled: true,
                                         format: '{point.name}'
                                     }


                                 })
                            },
                            drillup: function(){

                            }
                        }
                    },

                    series: [{

                        data: data,
                        joinBy: ['postal-code', 'code'],
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled:true,
                            color: '#FFFFFF',
                            format: '{point.name}'
                        }
                    }],
                }
            }
        }
    },

}


</script>
```

Because the chart has 'chart': 'us' option, it renders US map first. Then, when I click any state (just for a test) it switches US map to world map. 
It renders world map. However, it also render US map too. That is, it renders both two maps. How can I fix it??

Comment: I have an error on my code.  in 'this.addSeriesAsDrilldown' function, I should delete data:'world' .  What I want to do is, when I click any state of US, it renders nothing, because I didn't set any maps to switch. However, It renders US map again.

Comment: Would you like to achieve something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/njcd48yb/